# Django - urls.py in project, and url.py in app

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a form action redirect to another page, however, I'm not too farmiliar with the Django framework. I went through the polls tutorial.

The current urls.py in my project is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from WebApp import views
from StripCal import views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^webapp/', include('WebApp.urls', namespace="WebApp")),
    url(r'^stripcal/', include('StripCal.urls', namespace="StripCal")),
)

The url.py in my stripcal app is:

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from StripCal import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^run', views.detail, name='detail'),
)
```

When I type in

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/stripcal/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/webapp/
```

It successfully goes to two different apps. However, I'm not too familiar with {% url 'app_name:view_name' %} syntax. It seems like 'app_name:view_name' becomes /app_name/view_name

This is my current view:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    context = {'somethingDownByCelery': "heh"}
    return render(request, 'StripCal/index.html', context)

def detail(request):
    context = {'somethingDownByCelery': "heh"}
    return render(request, 'StripCal/detail.html', context)
```

My Index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'StripCal/index.css' %}"/>

<form action="{% url 'stripcal:detail'%}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p> StripCal Input </p>
    <textarea name="StripCal_Input" cols="30" rows="10"> </textarea>
    <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My Detail.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'StripCal/detail.css' %}"/>

Hello Detail!
```

When I remove action={% url 'stripcal:detail' %} the webpage loads, however, when I put it in, the page does not even load (HTTP 500).

Comment: 1) is it `url.py` or `urls.py` in your app dir? 2) Do you have `DEBUG = TRUE` turned on in your `settings.py`? 3) Your namespace is CamelCase, I would make the url CamelCase as well in `<form action=..`

Comment: It is urls.py, sorry for the typo, I've updated the post. Currently debug = false because there is a celery task currently in the background doing database work. And debug = true will increase memory usage. Also, what do you mean by CamelCase?

Comment: It seems that debug = True has my answers :c, sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change:
StripCal.url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('StripCal.views',
url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
url(r'^run','detail', name='detail'),
```

)